# fancydropdown js: Invalid argument in IE8

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using fancydropdown.js for a drop down and an image slide show. on the page, I am facing an issue in JavaScript, its giving an error and the image slide show is not working.

> SCRIPT87: Invalid argument.  fancydropdown.js, line 15 character 12983
>
> ***{J[G]=K}***

Kindly check the following URL for code. http://jsfiddle.net/santoshshelke/vmsX3/

Thanks in advance

Comment: please post your code (javascript and html).

Comment: Can you add the JavaScript here?

Comment: Did you just link a jsFiddle of the jQuery source code?

Comment: you can select the jQuery 1.3.2 version in [the dropdown list to the left](http://jsfiddle.net/vmsX3/1/).... much easier :)

Comment: @Aesthete Yes I have just add jQuery source code.

Comment: @SantoshShelke - Ok well this doesn't help because you're passing an invalid argument to a jQuery function, and we need to see where it's coming from. Where's **your** code?

Comment: @Aesthete http://center.podsdemo.com/Home/Home This is page URL, check in the IE8.

Comment: Thanks guys, I have solved this issue.
Replace jQuery version 1.3.2 to 1.8.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace jQuery version 1.3.2 to 1.8.0